# Twilio - How to use global twilio number in all sub accounts (already buy twilio number for main account)

Tags: notifications, twilio, whatsapp

- Twilio - How to use global twilio number in all sub accounts.

  - I already buy twilio number for main account, i will use this number in all sub account.

    ### - It is possible or not if yes then tell me steps for same.

  Thanks,
  Nikunj Limbani

Answer (score 0):

a Twilio number can only be used in the Account SID it belongs to (so it cannot be shared across sub-accounts). Do you have any details on what you are trying to achieve by doing so?